# createPortal - TypeScript document.getElementById type issue when JavaScript runs fine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use ReactDOM.createPortal and neither 'ReactDOM' or 'document' is highlighted in VSCode and I get this error when hovering over 'document.getElementById('overlay-root')':

```
Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

Here's the code:

```
import styles from './CartModal.module.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Card from '../UI/Card/Card';

interface CartModalProps {
  onClose?: () => void
}

const DisplayCartModal: React.FC<CartModalProps> = (props) => {

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <>
      <CartModal />
    </>, 
    document.getElementById('overlay-root')
  )
}

export default DisplayCartModal;
```

I've tried switching the file extension to .js to see if this is a TypeScript error and indeed when I changed it (and removed TS-specific syntax) everything was highlighted and worked perfectly. It did not return null, it returned the correct HTML Element. Help is *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is, `document.getElementById('overlay-root')` *might* be null.  You (I assume) know that it will not be, but Typescript does not know that.

You can assert that not-null-ness with an exclamation mark, like so:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(
<>
  <CartModal />
</>, 
document.getElementById('overlay-root')!
)
```

If your assertion is false, you will get a run-time error, a very bad thing.

Comment: Thank you very much; I ended up going the assertion route and everything works great.

Answer (score 5):

**In typescript, `createPortal` receive container of type `Element`:**

```
export function createPortal(children: ReactNode, container: Element, key?: null | string): ReactPortal;
```

**Meanwhile, `document.querySelector` return an Element OR Null**

```
querySelector<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): E | null;
```

This is a mismatch for both, to fix this, you will need to cast the return object from `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector('#overlay-root') as Element,
```

### **But for the sake of catching any errors, you should check for null before using it so you won't have to cast at all:**

```
const DisplayCartModal: React.FC<CartModalProps> = (props) => {
  const overlayRootEl = document.querySelector('#overlay-root');

  return overlayRootEl
    ? ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <>
        <CartModal />
      </>,
      overlayRootEl,
    )
    : null;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up going with an assertion (!) after the document.getElementById('overlay-root') statement and everything worked fine. I appreciate your contribution!